# Listing of Kill/Assist Rewards/Bonuses in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm trying to find a listing of information on how kills/assists are rewarded in League of Legends.  For instance, you get a certain amount of money for a standard champion kill.  What about for an assist?  How about for first blood?  Kill streak of 4?  Shutting down someone with a kill streak of 5?  How about for an ace?

Where can I find information on any and all rewards/bonuses you receive for killing or assisting in a kill on champion(s) in League of Legends?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The League of Legends Wiki lists all of this. A table for the rewards for kills is shown in [their Kill article](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kill), which I will mock-up below. Note that as of [V1.0.0.152](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.152), the bounty values were reworked to increase the effect of each kill or death. The table shown below reflects the *current* bounty rewards as of said patch.

```
K/D Count = Killstreak/Deathstreak count for the champion slain
K Reward = Improved reward for killing a champion with that kill streak
D Reward = Reduced reward for killing a champion who is getting hosed

K/D Count | K Reward | D Reward
----------+----------+---------
    1     |   300    |   300   
    2     |   360    |   260   
    3     |   432    |   182   
    4     |   500    |   127
```

The Kill article notes that a first blood has a +100 gold bonus, so the first blood will always be +400 (as [this question leads me to believe that executions don't increment your death streak](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-do-executions-work-in-league-of-legends)).

The other point to take home is that multi-kills and aces do not provide any bonus. Likewise, getting a killstreak doesn't get *you* any additional reward, only the person who finally takes you down.

The article for [Assist](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Assist) states that there is a pot of 70% of the kill bounty that is split between all champions that provided an assist for a particular takedown.

Comment: Wait, you get less gold form a champion who has a death streak? I had NO idea!

Comment: @danixd After a point, someone who just gets picked off all the time at the start of a team fight isn't remotely worth as much as someone who gives you a tough challenge. It also makes feeding *slightly* less worse in the gold department, though obviously there are lots of other problems it causes.

Comment: @Grace Note Thats really cool, I have 500+ normal wins about about 25 ranked and had no clue about this. Good idea from RIOT, thanks for the info.

Comment: Awesome post!  A lot of great information in there @GraceNote, some of which I had no idea about!

Comment: @danidx surpriesed you didnt notice such thing, apparently you dont play custom games nor Co.op vs A.I?

Comment: @camiloqp naw I only really play custom to practice jungling, and I rarely play Co-op vs AI. It is too easy and pretty dull. Humans are much more challenging :)

Comment: @Grace Patch 1.0.0.120 introduced some changes in gold reward system. Maximum gold is now 500 and minimum is 15, but unfortunately I don't have the details of formula used for intermediate levels so I cannot help changing your answer. [Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.120)

Comment: @Drake I noticed that. Once I can figure the better details I'll fix up the table.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your questions are answered on [Wikia:Gold](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gold)

There is no chart, but you'll find interesting information.

Answer (score 0):

Season 4 introduces many changes to the old system of kill and assist rewards.

While the Killstreak and Deathstreak tables are the same, the mechanics around the rewards are now different.

In order to reduce the effect of early-game wins (such as a level 1 teamfight), the gold bounty is being reduced to 60% at the beginning of the game. From 2 minutes to 4 minutes, the gold bounty scales linearly up to the full value.

Assists are also being reworked to benefit players who tend to get more assists than kills. In addition to their take of the assist pot, players with 2 more assists than kills gain 30 gold per assist. This increases to 45 gold for players with 3 more assists than kills, and 60 gold for players with more than 3 more assists than kills.

The amount of gold in the assist pot is changing as well. Until 20 minutes into the game, the assist pot is worth 50% of the kill bounty. This scales linearly up to 80% at 35 minutes into the game.

Finally, to counteract proxy farmers, players currently on a death spree will have their deathstreak reduced by 1 stage per 1000 gold earned from minions and monsters.