# How are the value of assists and kills determined in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the formula for calculating the value of a kill or an assist? Is it worth more gold for a team to get an assist and kill (AKA KS=kill securing) or is it better to allow the carry to get the whole kill with no assists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First blood - first kill of the game - is worth 400 gold to the person who gets the kill.

After that, a kill's base value is 300 gold for the person who gets the kill.  This number is then modified based on a "death streak", by 15% (iirc) for each consecutive death.  This is to reduce the effect a bad player has on a game.  So a person who dies 5 straight times (without themselves getting a kill) is worth less than 300 gold.  I think that's 133 gold.  Note that if a player on a death streak gets a kill their value resets.  Conversely, players who rack up kill streaks become worth more money.  They accrue a bounty that is awarded to whoever kills them and end their kill streak.   You can see the bounty values [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24483/listing-of-kill-assist-rewards-bonuses-in-lol/24484#24484).

Note that executions (deaths to a turret, minion, or neutral creep) do not count as kills.

Assists are trickier.  Anyone who does damage in the last 10 seconds splits money from the "assist pool", which is 58% of the value of the kill.  The assist pool is divied up among all assisters.  Also, other things can earn an assist, like healing the person who gets the kills.  Other buffs might contribute as well but I am unsure.

Comment: Attack speed increase/decrease and movement boost / slows also count for assists.

Comment: So does assisting in the kill make the main killer lose any gold value?

Comment: no, the killer always gets the full amount no matter what

Comment: Source? I only ask because I've been yelled at differently

Comment: Well, you can look at the wiki article I linked (sorry, it was removed, try here:  http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kill), but the killer always gets full value.  The person yelling is certainly ignorant and likely a moron.  Are you sure you weren't yelled at for kill stealing (note: it's stupid to complain about this too but never mind).

Comment: I was, I had it backwards in my brain for some reason. I blame classes starting yesterday.

Comment: Sunspots are another good blame fallback!

Comment: Another thing to note is that they recently changed the way assists affect a champions worth on death. They made assisters like soraka who can have a good game at 0/6/27 worth more money than they used to be. They also changed the way deaths to towers work. An execution death no longer resets your k/d as calculated in the link in the main answer above.